# Android get Uri from file from raw folder usin the name

Tags: android

I was reading about a solution for this problem. I have this code

```
String filename = "android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/raw/" + lastButtonFilename;
try {
    Log.i("Home", "Recreamos la URL: " + filename);
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(filename));
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Home", "Error setting source media." + e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

This is a screenshot of my app in Android Studio:
[image]
I see this logs:

```
02-06 17:49:28.605 28884-28884/com.mypackage I/Home: Recreamos la URL: android.resource://com.mypackage/raw/sound_test.mp3
02-06 17:49:28.614 28884-28884/com.mypackage W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No resource found for: android.resource://com.mypackage/raw/sound_test.mp3
```

I have sound_test.mp3 in my *src/res/raw* folder. Im using **Android Studio**. I had created the URI from the correct path (I think). Can't be something wrong?

Comment: Get rid of all of that and use [the version of `create()` that takes a resource ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context,%20int)).

Comment: I have to extract the file dinamically, because I know at runtime that file choose the user, It's difficult know the id in these time.

Comment: It would appear that `setDataSource()` does not accept `android.resource` schemes, though, so I do not think you have much of a choice.

Comment: where you have created raw folder. provide simple screenshot of it

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(android.content.Context, android.net.Uri) Method have a Context - Uri form :) I add a Screenshot in the main post

Answer (score 1):

Change your code...

```
String videoUri = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sound_test;
```

This tutorial have video file but process is same for audio file.Source [Click here for more description](https://www.freelancer.pk/community/articles/video-playing-on-android-guide)